# Free functors having a left adjoint

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors

If $(T,\eta,\mu)$ is a monad over $C$ and $C^T$ is the category of $T$-algebras, is well known that the forgetful functor $U:C^T\to C$ has a left adjoint $F:C\to C^T$. Moreover, under certain conditions (for example that $T$ has a right adjoint), $U$ has a right adjoint too. So my question is if there are known conditions for which $F$ has a left adjoint.

Thanks in advance